# Can you read a file concurrently with writing to a file using file_put_contents?

Tags: php

When a user lands on the page, I want to write some information about their browser/ip/location to a file.
At the top of the file I have some PHP code that checks my cookie and if I am admin will echo the contents of the file to the page so I can see the list of visitor data (using file_get_contents). I am going to make a function that will display the data in a table at some point.

I am tempted to use file_put_contents with the FILE_APPEND flag is set because it looks easy to use. Would there be any file permission conflicts with reading and writing to the file, and if so, how does fopen/fwrite avoid this conflict?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

fopen / fwrite don't avoid file permission conflicts. file_put_contents at some level is using fopen / fwrite. They merely ask the kernel to open some file for reading / writing / appending and the kernel says yes or no. If the kernel says no it will give some reason, such as no permission.

The program in which you are using fopen / fwrite is run by some user and group. If the file user and/or group permission allow your process to fopen / fwrite, then you can. If not, then you receive a no permission error.

The easiest thing to do is set the user / group on your file to the user / group that is running your PHP program. This is most likely the user / group the your web server is using, but need not be in every setup.

You may also consider using `is_readable` and `is_writable` to check for permission first.

Comment: I just want to make sure that if there is say 10 visitors to the site in the same second, and I happen to read the file within that second, that all 10 visitors will still be recorded, and that I can view the file. But there seems to be a lot of caveats with these functions that I can't understand to make sure that they can be used safely